# java eclipse regex cant "\+"

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

I need to check a String is `"\++?"` which will match something like `+6014456`

But I get this error message `invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\)` ....  why?

Comment: post your `.matches()` call. It's not obvious what are your actual arguments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's giving you an error because `"\++?"` isn't a valid Java literal - you need to escape the backslash. Try this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\++?");
```

However, I don't think that's *actually* the regular expression you want. Don't you actually mean something like:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\+\\d+");
```

That corresponds to a regular expression of `\+\d+`, i.e. a plus followed by at least one digit.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use two backslashes. One for escaping the second (because it's a java string), the second for escaping the + (because it's a special character for regex).

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't it be more like "\\+?" ?

---

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\++?");
System.out.println(pattern.matcher("+9970").find());
```

works for me